# Jquery plugin call not compatible with IE8

Tags: jquery, plugins, internet-explorer-8

I'm a newbie to the world of Jquery and plugins. I've been experimenting with the serialscroll plugin as explained here-- http://flesler.blogspot.com/2008/02/jqueryserialscroll.html. I have this simple code defining the parameters:

```
jQuery(function( $ ){

        $('#screen').serialScroll({
        target:'#sections',
        items:'li', 
        axis:'xy',
        navigation:'#navigation li a',
        duration:700,
        force:true, 
            });
    });
```

Works perfectly in all browsers except IE8 . Gives an error "Jquery not defined line 1 char 1." Obviously I've the latest external serialscroll.js file so I know that's not the problem. Is the syntax something that IE8 is not happy with ?

Here is the full code :

JQUERY:

```
// Easing equation, borrowed from jQuery easing plugin
// http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/
jQuery.easing.easeOutQuart = function (x, t, b, c, d) {
    return -c * ((t=t/d-1)*t*t*t - 1) + b;
};

jQuery(function( $ ){

    $('#screen').serialScroll({
        target:'#sections',
        items:'li', 
        axis:'xy',
        navigation:'#navigation li a',
        duration:700,
        force:true, 
        onBefore:function( e, elem, $pane, $items, pos ){
            e.preventDefault();
            if( this.blur )
                this.blur();
        },
        onAfter:function( elem ){

        }
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#screen{
    position:relative;
    height:700px;
    width:925px;
    margin-top:40px;
    }
#navigation{
    position:absolute;
    width:883px;
    height:77px;
    z-index:3;
    left: 84px;
    top: -17px;
        }
        #navigation ul{
            margin-left:10px !important;

        }
            #navigation li{
                float:left;
                padding-left:35px;


            }
                #navigation a{
                    font-weight:bolder;
                    text-decoration:none;
                    padding-left:25px;
                    float:left;
                }

#sections{
    position:absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:510px;
    height:510px;
    z-index:3;
    left: 169px;
    top: 205px;
}

    #sections ul{
        width:3660px;
            }

        #sections li{
            left: 0px;
            top: 0px;
            padding-left:0;
            margin-left:0;
        }
        #sections p{
                width:550px;
                margin:16px 0;
                font-size:85%;
                line-height:1.4em;}
```

HTML :

```
<div id="screen">

<div id="navigation">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
</div>

<div id="sections"><ul>
<li><p>some text</p></li>
<li><p>some text</p></li>
<li><p>some text</p></li>
<li><p>some text</p></li>
</ul></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the trailing comma on the line `force:true,` (so it reads `force:true`) - Internet Explorer does not like in the slightest when there is a comma but no additional property after it.

Comment: @Nathan Anderson, Got rid of the comma but still no go. Gives the same error "Jquery not defined line 1 char 1."

Comment: You almost certainly have a similar javascript syntax error elsewhere. IE is much more strict about JS syntax than other browsers. Look for extra comma, missing semicolon, something like that.

Comment: I agree with @jamietre.  If possible, post your complete page somewhere it can be reviewed.

Comment: @jamietre : I completely agree but the question is where? :)

Comment: @Nathan Anderson : See the full code above. I tried it without the easing function just to isolate where the problem was

Comment: Some updates on this issue: 

1. I changed the <script type="text/javascript" > to <script type="application/javascript" > and the error went away in IE8

2. The initial code I posted was just not compatible with the serialscroll plugin when it came to IE8 . I rewrote the code and in a different way and now it works.

3. IE sucks and its really troubles me that since half the population still uses IE, half the developers in the world (if not all) have to suffer !